# How to split string by space, that is not wrapped by specified characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to write regexp, that would be possible to split specified string via spaces, that are not wrapped with some special symbols (quotes & brackets). For following string:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2015:01:21:01 +0300] "GET /status.xsl HTTP/1.1"
```

I need to get following answer:

1. 127.0.0.1
2. -
3.   -
4. 16/Jun/2015:01:21:01 +0300
5. GET /status.xsl HTTP/1.1

It is simple to match all quoted strings: `"([^"]+)"`, same for brackets `\[([^\]]+)\]`

It is simple to match all non-space characters: `\S+`

I am confused because of those conditions. Is it possible to perform such operation with one regexp? Or i should use different approach to perform this?

Comment: Can you not use a csv parser?

Comment: Is there any need to escape the brackets? i.e. do you ever have for example a string containing "["

Comment: Can't you just match the string instead of splitting? That would make this easier.

Comment: This is really easy using RegExp using capture groups. However, the pattern would be long though.

Comment: @TimB nope, no need to escape brackets or quotes

Comment: @amal-murali no problem with just matching.. i just need to get this data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide more input examples can be possible to refine the answer, in the meantime if you want to try another approach you can use `split()`:

```js
input = '127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2015:01:21:01 +0300] "GET /status.xsl HTTP/1.1"';

results = input.split(/(?=[-\[\]"])[" \]\[]|[ "\[\]](?=[-\[\]"])/).filter(function(e){ return e === 0 || e });

document.write(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
\"([^\"]+)\"|\[([^\]]+)\]|([^ ]+)
```

Comment: will that handle lines with two fields wrapped in []? Since every space between those two fields would be between [ and ]

Comment: I believe it would, the [] is first and should be resolved first.

I tested it out here. http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite what you're after, but when parsing a web access log there are certain patterns you might be able to account for up front.

In your case the 2 or 3 "known" fake spaces are before the timezone in the date, after the HTTP action for the URL, and before the HTTP version.

e.g. The space after "GET" (or POST, PUT...) before the URL is a known space, but not a delimiter between individual values.  If you replaced all occurrences of `"GET` with `"GET{FAKE_SPACE}` and the space for the timezone `:01 +0300` (say `/(:\d\d)(\s)/`) first... then you can just split the remaining by spaces and have the items you want. (You'll want to revert the `{FAKE_SPACE}` tokens afterwards of course)